# How to add TextView automatically base on TABLE rows

Tags: android

Good day! How can I add TextView automatically base on table rows and display the row data in the generated TextView, or is there another way to accomplish this.

```
Row 1
    PA : Savings Account // Col 1
    2015-08-17           // Col 2  
    483.67               // Col 3
    483.67               // Col 4

Row 2
    PA : Savings - Cash Bond // Col 1
    2015-08-28               // Col 2
    10129.43                 // Col 3
    10129.43                 // Col 4
```

this is my current code

```
 private TextView textView_SL_Desc;
 private TextView textView_SL_Bal;

 textView_SL_Desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sl_desc);
 textView_SL_Bal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actual_balance);

 // Fetching USER sl details from SQlite
 HashMap<String, String> sl_summ = db.getUserSLDTL();
 String sl_desc = sl_summ.get("sl_desc");
 String actual_balance = sl_summ.get("actual_balance");

 //Set text to text view
 textView_SL_Desc.setText(sl_desc);
 textView_SL_Bal.setText(actual_balance);
```

My XML

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/sl_desc"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="13sp" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/actual_balance"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="13sp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) will solve your problem for dynamically creating a list of views (in your case, your XML file) in an efficient way.

How to use RecyclerView:

1. Create a ViewHolder class to hold your TextView widgets

   ```
   public class RowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final TextView textView_SL_Desc;
        public final TextView textView_SL_Bal;

        public RowViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView_SL_Desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sl_desc);
            textView_SL_Bal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.actual_balance);
        }
   }
   ```
2. Create a RecylerView.Adapter class to bind your data with your UI (something similar to two-way binding model if you are familiar with AngularJS)

   ```
   public class RecyclerAdapter RecyclerView.Adapter<RowViewHolder> {
       private List<HashMap<String, String>> sl_summList;

       public RecyclerAdapter(List<HashMap<String, String>> sl_sumnList) {
                   this.sl_sumnList = sl_sumnList;
       }

       // This is the code where RecyclerView knows how to create views from your ViewHolder class (in this case, RowViewHolder)            
       @Override
       public RowViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml_layout, parent, false);
           return new RowViewHolder(view);
       }

       // This is the code where RecyclerView populates data (binds data to UI)
       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(RowViewHolder holder, int position) {
           // This is the code where you get data based on position of the table. I cannot write specific code because I don't know how your hashmap looks like
           String sl_summ = this.sl_sumnList.get(position);
           holder.textView_SL_Desc.setText(sl_summ.get("sl_desc"));
           holder.textView_SL_Bal.setText(sl_summ.get("actual_balance"));
       }

       // How RecyclerView knows how many items are in the list
       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return sl_sumnList.size();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Hooks RecyclerView with your RecylerView.Adapter class

   ```
       mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.your_recycler_view_id);

       LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

       List<HashMap<String,String> dbRowList = db.get_all_rows(); // get all items from your database)
       mRecyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(dbRowList);
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter); // finally hooks up RecyclerView.Adapter with RecyclerView.
   ```

Here is an official tutorial of ReyclerView, https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html.

Answer (score 0):

You should explore [ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) and [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) for displaying dynamic list of data (in your case table rows).

You can have your own designed ListView to display data in specific manner.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to accomplish this. 
I prefer to add Linearlayouts dynamically. It´s easy and you can Display nearly every data you want.

First: Take your .xml file and name it into "show_data_item"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:id="@+id/show_data_item">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2sp"
    android:background="#000000"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="2sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Display Data Col1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="2sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col2"
        android:text="Display Data Col2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="2sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2sp"
    android:background="#000000"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="0sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="2sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Display Data Col3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="2sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/col4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Display Data Col4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="2sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2sp"
    android:background="#000000"/>


  </LinearLayout>
```

Step 2: Create an xml Layout for your activity and don´t forget to add it to "manifest.xml", like this (made it with a scrollview so that you have unlimited space) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/displaydata"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Step 3: Create an class in java which fill´s the textviews with your col1-4, and add this to your "id/displaydata" with the funktion:

```
  myView.addview(show_data_item); //myView is an Object of LinearLayout and show_data_item is also a object of LinearLayout.
```

[This is how you do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view/%22Like%20this%22)

You can also use a List/RecylerView and add your data with an Adapter. You still need an Layout for your show_data_item.

[Here is a code example for this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)

All ways leads to rome, i guess.